# Resize a WriteableBitmap in C# for WindowsPhone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmap, crop

How do I resize a WriteableBitmap to where it goes from 2768x2768 to 1500x1500?

I can't find any scalable options, and all the other code is incompatible with W

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resize your image using the below code

```
    public byte[] ChangeDimension(BitmapImage bitmapImage, int width, int height)
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
            wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream,width, height, 0, 100);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            data = stream.GetBuffer();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the nuget package `WriteableBitmapEx` (writeable bitmap extensions).

It provides a `Resize()` extension method.

Another option would be the [PictureDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff708027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class, it allows to load a scaled version of the image (If it's a JPEG).

Comment: These aren't working I'm still getting the "Image too large" error. My OCR library will only allow for 2600x2600 pixelwdith/pixelheight and after cropping/resizing with this tool I'm still receiving the error.

Comment: ah right, there is a size restriction on writeablebitmaps, it's 2000x2000

Comment: Well AT LEAST 2600x2600. The images I take with my back camera come out to be 2000x2000, so I guess that's good. I need them to be cropped to 800x600

Comment: Also I'm reading these values in PixelWidth/PixelHeight. How do I lower these?

Comment: If I get you right, your problem is not resizing the bitmap, but the OCR library that gives an error?